# how to fix executable path in chrome driver error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selelium.webdriver.common.keys import keys
from time import sleep
driver = webdriver.chrome(executable_path="C:\Users\dontr\Downloads\chromedriver_win32 (1)\chromedriver.exe")
```

whenever I run the script I get a syntax error, i have everything downloaded. selenium, chromedriver, I even added it to the path correctly. I think the executable path is broken or something.

Comment: What’s the error message?

Comment: (unicode erre) 'unicodeescape' codec cant decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: Instead of `webdriver.chrome()` it should be `webdriver.Chrome()` Also change the backward slashes to forward slashes `/`

Answer (score 0):

There are spelling mistakes in your code, selenium spell wrong 2nd line and `Keys` instead of keys:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Users\dontr\Downloads\chromedriver_win32 (1)\chromedriver.exe")
```